# Entity Framework 6 -required properties

Tags: entity-framework-6, models

I am developing a project in asp.net mvc 5 + EF6. All my entities have been modeled the way they should....I have repeated this process several times in my project, now I am having and issue with [required] properties. Let's say for instance, I have 10 properties in my model class from which 4 of them I have marked as {Required]...so, the other 6 properties can allow nullable values...aren't validated in my model, so the user doesn't have to provide a value for those properties in the view...just the required ones are mandatory.

The thing is that there are some properties apart from those I set up as Required that are also required despite I didn't do it...in my model just 4 properties are marked required...but in my view somehow is validated as required more than 4 properties...

When I check my migration file related to that model change..I have realized that those properties I am refering apear this way:
...
`ContactName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50),`
...
I'm afraid that is I change this migration file, and set nullable to true, or drop the the entire info between paretheses and rerun the migration I will get an error since EF will try to create a table that already exist.
Someone could tell me what's happening...and a possible solution..

Thanks.

Comment: Don't change the migration file (code first) - change the models and add another migration. EF won't drop existing tables when you have migrations enabled.

Comment: Thank you Steve...I followed your advice.